# How to change string inside word only once using str_replace or other function?

Tags: php, string, str-replace

I need to chnage some words inside strings - I must separate string on 2 or more words - or to add space before and after word. For example I have shopifystore - this must be separated into 2 words": shopify and store, so result must be: "shopify store". One more example - I have dogsstore - this must be separated into 2 words": dogs and store, so result must be: "dogs  store"

So, I write some function, but results are not so good. My function:

```
function englishchange($string) {
$latin = array('dogs','dog','stores','store','shops','shop','shopify');
$latinchanged = array(' dogs ',' dog ',' stores ',' store ',' shops ',' shop ',' shopify ');
return str_replace($latin, $latinchanged, $string);
}
$englishchanged = (englishchange('shopifystore'));
```

But the resilt from "dogsstore" is: "dog s store" and "shopifystore" going to: "shop ify store". Can anyone help me, please, to rewrite php code to  get the right result?

Comment: Wouldn't it suffice to just replace "store" with " store"? And/or "stores" with " stores"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`strtr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php) in its second form to do  the replacements. In that mode, it takes an array of replacement pairs and, working from the longest strings downward, having made a replacement, it will not replace that substring again. So you just need to combine your `$latin` and `$latinchanged` arrays into an array using [`array_combine`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) and then call `strtr`:

```
function englishchange($string) {
$latin = array('dogs','dog','stores','store','shops','shop','shopify');
$latinchanged = array(' dogs ',' dog ',' stores ',' store ',' shops ',' shop ',' shopify ');
return strtr($string, array_combine($latin, $latinchanged));
}
$englishchanged = (englishchange('dogsstore shopifystore'));
echo $englishchanged;
```

Output:

```
 dogs  store   shopify  store
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the string matches several search items.
You can assume that you want only one change per string so you could procede with a loop to avoid the problem :

```
function englishchange($string)
{
    $latin = array('dogs','dog','stores','store','shops','shop','shopify');
    $latinchanged = array(' dogs ',' dog ',' stores ',' store ',' shops ',' shop ',' shopify ');
    foreach ($latin as $key => $item) {
        if (strpos($string, $item) !== false) {
            return str_replace($item, $latinchanged[$key], $string);
        }
    }
}
```

This way the altered string will be returned after the first replacement.